# Why does paint work without being called?

Tags: java, swing

Here is a simple program that suppose to draw many circles with a same center.

But should not I need something like `frame.paint(null)` in the `main()`? Why is this program working **without calling** the `paint()`?

```
package circle;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class NewCircle extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new NewCircle();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600,  600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("circle 99", 20, 20);

        int x0 = getSize().width/2;
        int y0 = getSize().height/2;

        for(int r=0 ; r<getSize().height/2; r+=10) {

            g.drawOval(x0-r,y0-r,r*2,r*2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Swing-Framework has a thread that runs in the background which automatically paints all components when it thinks they should be redrawn. You don't need to call it manually. And if you want to trigger it, call `repaint()`.

Comment: Start by having a read through [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for a better understanding of how painting works in Swing.  Also, avoid overriding `paint`, especially of top level containers like `JFrame`, as it's not double buffered and your locking yourself into a single use case

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when I replace JFrame frame = new NewCircle(); with NewCircle frame = new NewCircle(); It still paints, why? Please advise. Thank you

Comment: @perryfanfan Because that doesn't change the fact that `NewCircle` is still a `JFrame` as you have `extends JFrame`. The constructor of `JFrame` registers at the swing thread which automatically draws all swing components. The only thing your modified code does is not restricting the view to the instance. I.e. not implicitly casting.